# Threaded Python program not running smoothly on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I'm making a line following robot for a school project based on the Raspberry Pi 3. The robot has an LED sign on top, that I want to fade up and down while the robot is running. I'm running the fading method in a separate thread to avoid "time.sleep()" interfering with the main code.

```
class blinkSign(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        oneSign.start(0)    # Start PWM @ 0% duty cycle
        fiveSign.start(0)
        while 1:
            for i in range(20, 100, 1):
                oneSign.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
                fiveSign.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
                time.sleep(0.01)

            for j in range(100, 20, -1):
                oneSign.ChangeDutyCycle(j)
                fiveSign.ChangeDutyCycle(j)
                time.sleep(0.01)


def readButtons():
    startButton = GPIO.input(button1)
    stopButton = GPIO.input(button3)
    if ((savePress.prev_input1) and not startButton):
        print("start pressed")
        startFlag.started = 1
    if ((savePress.prev_input2) and not stopButton):
        print("Stop pressed")
        startFlag.started = 0

    savePress.prev_input1 = startButton
    savePress.prev_input2 = stopButton

try:
    blinkSign()
    while 1:
        readButtons()
        if (startFlag.started):
            decideSpeed()
        else:
            runMotor((0, 0))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("cleanup")
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I left out some of the code, since I deemed it non-important for the question. You can see it all on [Github](https://github.com/chrille94/RPi_test/blob/master/threadTestNew.py).

The problem is that the fading runs far from smoothly. In the first couple of seconds it does what it's supposed to, but then it gets slower and slower and finally seems to halt completely. The main program seems unaffected. I tried running just the fading code (outside a class) and that works just fine. Is it something I'm doing wrong in my code, or is it a limitation of the Pi? And also, why does it run in the beginning but not later on?

Comment: I don't see an actual bug in your implementation, but it seems you are victim to the complexities of the PI and running Python on it. My personal experience: don't use RPI.GPIO. The alternative PIGPIO is *much* better. Also, don't use threads as if they are for free. They aren't, especially not in Python. Python can always only ever run *one* thread at a given time through the GIL. As the PWM manipulation is comparatively slow, make it happen from the mainloop by calling into your blinkSign class. Take timestamps and decide what to do based on the elapsed time  instead of running the thread.

Comment: The main thread seems to run continuously. Python has a GIL which allows only one thread to run (some exceptions apply). Try to add a short `sleep()` to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! @deets, changing the code to work with pigpio instead of RPi.GPIO did the trick.